# Automatically Updating AMI using FTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-instance-store

I am using AWS and have setup and Instance for my site. I have then created an AMI for this instance and setup load balancing to spin up additional instances when the CPU process gets to 60%+ which is working fine. I want to update the website but cannot update the AMI directly as it is just an image of the main instance.

My current process would be to update the main instance and then create a new AMI and map the load balancing to use this new AMI but that seems long winded, is there a quicker way to update a single instance and have the load balanced served instances use this updated main instance.

I want to be able to;

1. Update an Instance through FTP
2. This automatically update the AMI
3. The instances created using the Load Balancer then use this new AMI

If this is not possible can you let me know how you are meant to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked properly with AWS, but you can script what you describe above. Creating a new image and changing the EBS config isn't that hard, at least not as far as I can remember. Once you have the script, you might be able to set up your FTP-client to execute it once an upload is complete.

Amazon has lots of documentation on how to set up the AWS command line tools, this one is for ELB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTheCommandLineTools.html

The procedure is similar for EC2 as well.